# Raspberry Pi Mesh Network

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I want to set up a simple [mesh network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking) using Wifi among multiple Raspberry Pis. The goal is for multiple moving Pis to be able to join and leave the network and send GPS data to all nodes on the network.

I've looked into a few options (commotion, byzantium, anymesh, HSMM-pi) and I haven't been able to find anything that just gives me the mesh network without other features that aren't necessary for the project. If anyone can lead me in the right direction on how to configure the Pis or any projects that could help, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi you could look into the [PiVersify Ad-Hoc Networks Blog](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/147699665389/ad-hoc-networking-with-raspberry-pis) to create an ad-hoc network and then use meshing techniques to achieve your result